# Two php questions

Tags: php, arrays, list

How can I list IP addresses in an array in PHP without having to resort to regular expression to escape the periods?

```
<?php 
    $list = array( 
        "^12\.34\.", 
        "^12\.35\.", 
    );
```

And without having to put them all inside the brackets like this:

```
<?php
    $list = array ("12.34.","12.35.");
```

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
<?php 
    $list = array(include a list on a different page, without having to put it into syntax)
```

Comment: You may want to improve the title a bit, it doesn't give a lot of information.

Comment: A little confused at what you are trying to do.  Ip addresses in dot notation  can only be treated as strings...

Comment: You don't need to escape periods. I don't understand what the problem is?

Comment: But I do need to escape them if I have a large number of IPs. I can't go about adding escapes to all the strings, or do I have to?

Comment: As for the title, sorry, it was from a previous php question I never got round to posting, and it got stuck when I wrote this one.

Answer (score 0):

To add an IP into an array, all you need is this:

```
$array[] = $ip;
```

Your array will store the IP as a string with periods.

For example:

```
$array[] = '10.0.0.1';
print_r($array);
```

The output would look something like:

```
Array([0] => 10.0.0.1)
```

Comment: I don't think I made myself clear enough. I have a hundreds of strings of these IPs and I'd like to put them inside an array without having to resort to regexp, apostrophes or brackets. How could I do this?

Comment: @user1615434 You did not make that clear at all. We need to see a sample of what the array containing the IP's looks like.

Comment: I don't know how to press enter on this without it automatically going to -add comment-, so basically I'm looking for a way to have an array, like in the first example I gave, but without the apostrophes and the regex escapes. Do you think that's possible? It's just this way I would be able to easily include a page that would simply consist of the strings I want to include, without having to escape all its periods, or quote them.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a file structured something like:

```
123.123.123.123
234.234.234.234
1.2.3.4
2.3.4.5
```

If you're looking to add these all to an array, you could do `$f = file('ip.txt');` and then `$f` would be an array of string elements containing IP addresses from the file.